# Datagridview: How to change width of leftmost selection column?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

because of the data binding possibility I want to use a DataGridView.
But on my form I have very limited width.
There are a lot of questions and examples about changeing data column width.
What I don't like is that the leftmost select / insert column with the triangle is so wide.
Is there any possibility to make it narrower or to avoid display of this column?

Comment: Do you mean the RowHeader? Have you tested [RowHeadersWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheaderswidth)?

Comment: Ah, maybe. I didn't realize that it is a row header. To me it is a column. I will try.
You are correct. So easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the width of the index column/ left most coumn in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432776/how-to-change-the-width-of-the-index-column-left-most-coumn-in-datagridview)